# Desktop is restarting when CPU load more than 60%

Tags: cpu, cpu-usage, cooling

My desktop is restarting frequently when CPU load is 60% or more for few seconds. i cleaned CPU fan dusts but still it is happening. so what could be the problem?

Comment: Is this a pc you built yourself?  How long was the computer working before this issue arose(days or months)?  Possibly a power supply issue.. which would be cheaper than the CPU answer below.

Comment: Yes i assembled my PC 2 years before but last two days i am running with this issue. so i am feeling that issue by thermal paste so help me resolve this

Comment: It sounds like the PSU to me, but its difficult to diagnose honestly. Its possible that when under load your fans spin up and you overload your PSU... From my experience they tend to die silently.  Oh and I assume its rebooting w/o BSOD as well?

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the temperature of your CPU cores? Try applications such as Speedfan (http://www.almico.com/speedfan.php) and CoreTemp (http://www.alcpu.com/CoreTemp/) to check if the temperature of the cores rises over 70-80°C. If that's the case, should install more efficient cooling or underclock your CPU.

Answer (score 0):

heat. check that the cooling device is in contact with the CPU. a tiny space between them and the cooling is quite less efficient.